# r foreach parallel "incorrect number of dimensions"

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I want to scan through a large matrix. Here is a shorthand version of what I want to do. If, in the code I substitute %do% for %dopar%, it runs correctly, with dopar it gives  "incorrect number of dimensions" error

```
cfun <- function(a,b) NULL
a <- foreach (j = 1:185001, .combine='cfun') %dopar% {
Xlog_sum[j]<- sum(Xlog_bool[,j])
}
```

thanks

Comment: `colSums(Xlog_bool)`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "Xlog_sum" is a vector and "Xlog_bool" is a 2D matrix, you should not get an "incorrect number of dimensions" error. I ran this example, and the only problem is that all of the results are lost. "Xlog_sum" is not modified when using %dopar% because side effects are lost when running in parallel. You should only use %dopar% in a foreach loop if the loop can be executed in parallel, and this is an example of a foreach loop that doesn't work in parallel because it depends on side effects.

For foreach to work with both %do% and %dopar%, you have to collect the results using the combine function, as in:

```
Xlog_sum <- foreach(j = 1:185001, .combine='c') %dopar% {
  sum(Xlog_bool[,j])
}
```

Comment: I am doing a lot of calculations in the cycle. My question is : why does it work with %do% and why not with %dopar%?

Comment: The error might be caused by the fact that I am referencing ff files in the cycle... Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: @Judit Side effects in the foreach loop often work with %do%, whereas they almost never work with %dopar% since you're modifying objects that aren't sent back to the master process. That's why I noted that you "should return a value rather than modify a variable".